# python: how string.replace() in python works?

Tags: python, string, methods, output

In below example why 1st 'let' is not replaced instead 2nd and 3rd are replaced. can anyone help me why it choose 2nd and 3rd instead of 1st and 2nd 'let'?

```
song = 'cold, cold heart'
print (song.replace('cold', 'hurt'))

song = 'Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be'

'''only two occurences of 'let' is replaced'''

print(song.replace('let', "don't let", 2))
```

o/p

```
hurt, hurt heart

Let it be, don't let it be, don't let it be, let it be
```

Comment: it's case (so it ignores the first Let) and you used a count argument o 2

Answer (score 4):

`string.replace()` is case-sensitive. `"Let"` is not the same thing as `"let"`, thus when the method is looking for occurrences of `"let"`, it gets ignored.

Comment: Ignore - OP has issue with first `Let` and you correctly explain the issue.